# How do I set the cookie on the WebView2 control using the CoreWebView2CookieManager

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, webview2

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to set the cookie on my WPF based WebView2 browser control using the CoreWebView2CookieManager (CookieManagement API from WebView2 latest SDK 1.0.705.50), but the cookie is not getting set on the browser.

This is my piece of code in WPF application:

```
private void ButtonNavigateToLocal(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   string uri = @"http://www.dnndev.me/";
   var cookie = _webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie("TestCookie", "XJKDKD", ".me", null);
   cookie.IsHttpOnly = true;
   cookie.IsSecure = true;                
  _webView.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(cookie);           
  _webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(uri);

}
```

Just wanted to know if there is anything I am missing here ? Do i also need to use the WebResourceRequested event to set the cookie ? Any clues or example will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you know, it isn't set? How have you checked? Are you sure the domain is the same as in your `Source` ?

Comment: @Poul Bak : Yes, I checked on the Dev tools (Applications tab -->Cookies drop down), The source and domain were same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set cookie domain to a top level domain `.me`. That is not legal and browser won't send it for security reasons.

Just imagine if you set it to `.com` then it would send the cookie to half the world. So that's forbidden.

Instead set it to `.dnndev.me` - then it will be sent to your domain.

You also set: `cookie.IsSecure = true;` - then it will only be sent to `https` requests. Set that to `false` to include `http` requests.

Also set `path` to `/` - then it will be sent all paths on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set the cookie with your advise. Here is the change i did:

cookie.path = "/"; (The Cookie gets set when the path was "/" or null or string.empty), 
cookie.IsSecure = false;  
cookie.domain = ".dnndev.me";