# CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie() not working

Tags: c#, .net, webview2

Reg - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080024/how-do-i-set-the-cookie-on-the-webview2-control-using-the-corewebview2cookiemana/76160669#76160669:~:text=The%20problem%20is,on%20your%20server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080024/how-do-i-set-the-cookie-on-the-webview2-control-using-the-corewebview2cookiemana/76160669#76160669:%7E:text=The%20problem%20is,on%20your%20server).

```
var cookieUrl = $"{_uriScheme}://{cookie.Domain}{cookie.Path}"; 
var coreWebView2Cookie = _webView2.WebView2.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie(
   name: cookie.Name, 
   value: cookie.Value, 
   Domain: cookie.Domain, 
   Path: cookie.Path); 
_webView2.WebView2.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(coreWebView2Cookie));
```

Suppose if my url is like this

-> http://ob-341.dnndev.com/identityserver/core

What should I have to set as domain and path?

Comment: What have you currently set? Aka; an [mre]  to make sure we fully understand what doesn't work.

Comment: This is the code I'm using

var cookieUrl = $"{_uriScheme}://{cookie.Domain}{cookie.Path}";
var coreWebView2Cookie = _webView2.WebView2.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.CreateCookie(name: cookie.Name, value: cookie.Value, Domain: cookie.Domain, Path: cookie.Path);
_webView2.WebView2.CoreWebView2.CookieManager.AddOrUpdateCookie(coreWebView2Cookie));

Even after calling this AddOrUpdateCookie, Cookiemanager doesn't contain any cookies.

Comment: Let's say for example 

cookieUrl =  http://ob-341.dnndev.com/identityserver/core

I set the values of Domain and Path as "ob-341.dnndev.com" and "/identityserver/core" respectively.